# When my app is in Background It wont open at first time

Tags: android

In my application there is a splash screen in which I am downloading data ,then I am calling My next Activity "A"  by using

```
Intent intent;
intent = new Intent(SplashscreenActivity.this, A.class);
intent.putExtra("position",0);
intent.putExtra("flag",true);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

It opens app well then I pressed the home screen button which get app to the background.

When I opened App again  it would not open the app it just flashes and gives me log for Activity "A" and also when i check Logs it doesnot shows Splashsceen logs but it shows logs in Activity A and also shows intent data which I passes i.e. position and flag. 
I do not able to understand what is the problem Is it because of finish() I am calling in splashScreen.
How can I solve this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
     Intent intent;
     intent = new Intent(SplashscreenActivity.this, A.class);
      intent.putExtra("position",0);
       intent.putExtra("flag",true);
       startActivity(intent);
            finish();  // here your are killing the current  Activty so it doesnot came remove this line
```

Comment: no thats not the correct way of interpreting... finish is after the startactivity. finish is used so that the on pressing back button it wont display the prev. activity.